# Difference between a theorem and a law

Tags: definition

There are plenty of theorems out there as well as laws within mathematics.  For example, in Boolean algebra:

**Theorems**

- Idempotent
- Involution
- Theorem of Complementarity

**Laws**

- Commutative
- Associative
- Distributive

There are countless other examples out there, but my real question is this:  What makes a theorem a theorem and a law a law?

Comment: In these examples, "laws" are really **identities** that are satisfied/imposed on the algebra *a priori*, while the theorems are propositions that are *deduced* from those identities and other axioms.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Perhaps these are bad examples... this question arose as I was studying for my embedded circuits class... but I'm looking for a "in general" answer... if one exists.

Comment: @KronoS: It's nomenclature; what is the difference between "Theorem", "Proposition", "Lemma", and "Corollary"? Answer: the importance the author places on them. But generally speaking, "laws" are *a priori* restrictions/rules/identities, while "Theorems" are *invariably* "derived truths": conclusions that follow logically from whatever you are starting from. That is, "laws" are *a priori*, "theorems" are *a posteriori*. "Generally" speaking, anyway.

Comment: @Arturo: I think "law" is used much more generally, e.g. law of exponents, law of sines, parallelogram law, quadratic Reciprocity Law, Sylvester's law of inertia. "Law" is a bit old-fashioned, and tends to be used more frequently in applied math, e.g. physical laws.

Comment: @Bill: Fair point; certainly, very common in Physics (Hooke's, Fermat's, etc). Still, much like the difference between Theorem and Lemma. (Though, while there are a lot of famous "Lemmas", like Zorn's, Fatou's, etc., is there any equally famous "Corollary"?)

Comment: @Arturo Magidin Isn't arguably Fermat's Last Theorem just a simple corollary of Taniyama-Shimura?

Comment: @Billare: Well, T-S came *after* FLT; and my use of quotations was meant as quote: "Zorn's Lemma" and "Fatou's Lemma" are *called* lemmas. FLT is not called a "corollary". Is there any famous result that is routinely refered to as "xxx Corollary"?

Comment: @KronoS: As you see in comments, the distinction between “law” and other notions is not precise, unlike other things in mathematics. I even collected a list of 7 synonyms of the word “theorem”. It's going mad. :) The real distinction exists between a logical formula and a theorem. A theorem is a **proven** logical formula.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Theorems* are results proven from *axioms*, more specifically those of mathematical logic and the systems in question. *Laws* usually refer to axioms themselves, but can also refer to well-established and common formulas such as the *law of sines* and the *law of cosines*, which really are theorems.

In a particular context, *propositions* are the more trivial theorems, *lemmas* are intermediate results, while *corollaries* are results deduced easily from others. However, lemmas and corollaries may be major results on their own.

Note that a system may be given axioms in more ways than one. For example, we can use the *least upper bound axiom* to define the real numbers, or we can consider this axiom as a theorem if we were to construct the reals from the rationals using *Dedekind cuts* and prove it instead. The difference here lies in which axioms we choose to start with.

Comment: I am not so sure that laws "refer to axioms themselves."  Doesn't Bills comment give at east 5 examples otherwise?  To add a couple more, how about the law of large numbers, or the law of cosines.

Comment: Also, there is De Morgan's Laws.

Comment: Have a very, merry Christmas, Jasper Joy...oops, Jasper Loy!

Comment: @Jasper Perhaps a Christmas gift? ;-)

Comment: If laws are axioms, then the makers of PVS have made a mistake in their labeling (which I think is possible, but very unlikely), since they have laws being essentially identical to theorems, lemmas, propositions, corollaries, et al. See top of page 26 of this PDF: http://pvs.csl.sri.com/doc/pvs-language-reference.pdf

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem:
"A law or a principle is a theorem that applies in a wide range of circumstances. Examples include the law of large numbers, the law of cosines, Kolmogorov's zero-one law, Harnack's principle, the least upper bound principle, and the pigeonhole principle.["

Answer (score 0):

Theorems are deducted, laws are induced.

Theorems are deducted from axioms.
Laws are induced from observations.

A law can be used as an axiom or as a theorem of a theory.